# Scala compilation error where it is not detecting the change in the index.html to refer to a new model Quote

Tags: scala, playframework

I updated the Scala index view file according to this tutorial http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play/ and got the following error:
[image]

My code is as follows :

**Application.scala**

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import models.Quote

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
  Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready.",Quote("Citer les pensees des autres, c'est regretter de ne pas les avoir trouvees soi-meme.",
          "Sacha Guitry")))
}

}
```

**Quote.scala**

```
package models
case class Quote(text: String, author: String)
```

index.scala

```
@(message: String, quote: models.Quote)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.1") {

    <p>@quote.text<em> - @quote.author</em></p>

}
```

Play is running in auto reloading mode in the background using the following command

> ~ run

I cannot understand why I am getting this compile error. I even tried doing an eclipse Build All.

Answer (score 0):

```
where is the error?
```

**no suggestions available is not an error**. if you are getting any it will be in console.
some time in eclipse changes doesn't get immediately. Specially in `Ok()` statement.
you can clean your project your in eclipse.and refresh the project, and still it will there ignore it.

EDIT:
eclipsfy your project again can remove
try `play clean update compile eclipse ~run`

Comment: Eclipse is not detecting the change in the template of the format @(message: String, quote: models.Quote) Instead it is detecting the old template format @(message: String)

Comment: I have cleaned the project in eclipse and refreshed it as well. However, that doesnt seem to have affected the final build.